# Change the text of the label of the menu cells

Tags: ios, menu, swift

I downloaded as a sample file from Github ENSwiftSideMenu to take a cue for a possible menu in my app, the file MyMenuTableViewController.swift I wanted to change the strings that are found in the cells of the menu but I'm stuck in place following the part of the code. Thanks for the help everyone. Salvatore

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("CELL") as? UITableViewCell

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier: "CELL")
        cell!.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
        cell!.textLabel?.textColor = UIColor.darkGrayColor()
        let selectedBackgroundView = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, cell!.frame.size.width, cell!.frame.size.height))
        selectedBackgroundView.backgroundColor = UIColor.grayColor().colorWithAlphaComponent(0.2)
        cell!.selectedBackgroundView = selectedBackgroundView
    }

    cell!.textLabel?.text = "CELL \(indexPath.row+1)"

    return cell!
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 50.0
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    println("did select row: \(indexPath.row)")

    if (indexPath.row == selectedMenuItem) {
        return
    }
    selectedMenuItem = indexPath.row

    //Present new view controller
    let mainStoryboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main",bundle: nil)
    var destViewController : UIViewController
    switch (indexPath.row) {
    case 0:
        destViewController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("Home") as UIViewController
        break
    case 1:
        destViewController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("Profilo") as UIViewController
        break
    case 2:
        destViewController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("Notizie") as UIViewController
        break
    default:
        destViewController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("Impostazioni") as UIViewController
        break
    }
    sideMenuController()?.setContentViewController(destViewController)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use array and put get the string text from there

```
//Declare array
var yourArray = ["string1","string2","string3","string4"]

//In cellForRowAtIndexPath  
cell!.textLabel?.text = yourArray[indexPath.row]
```

replace above code with below

```
var yourArray = ["string1","string2","string3","string4"]
override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

// MARK: - Table view data source

override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return 4
}

 override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("CELL") as? UITableViewCell

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier: "CELL")
        cell!.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
        cell!.textLabel?.textColor = UIColor.darkGrayColor()
        let selectedBackgroundView = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, cell!.frame.size.width, cell!.frame.size.height))
        selectedBackgroundView.backgroundColor = UIColor.grayColor().colorWithAlphaComponent(0.2)
        cell!.selectedBackgroundView = selectedBackgroundView
    }

    cell!.textLabel?.text = yourArray[indexPath.row]//"ViewController #\(indexPath.row+1)"

    return cell!
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 50.0
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

println("did select row: \(indexPath.row)")

if (indexPath.row == selectedMenuItem) {
    return
}
selectedMenuItem = indexPath.row

//Present new view controller
let mainStoryboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main",bundle: nil)
var destViewController : UIViewController
switch (indexPath.row) {
case 0:
    destViewController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("Home") as UIViewController
    break
case 1:
    destViewController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("Profilo") as UIViewController
    break
case 2:
    destViewController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("Notizie") as UIViewController
    break
default:
    destViewController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("Impostazioni") as UIViewController
    break
}
sideMenuController()?.setContentViewController(destViewController)
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your immediate response I was snookered on this thing, but I would have a further question, the table I added an extra column to contain the images as I insert the chosen image to match the string? 
Thanks in advance for your help.